# Buffering spatialpoints and getting raster values from overlapping polygons

Tags: raster, r, polygon, buffer

I have a spatial points representing eDNA sample.
I have a raster file representing surface temperature (RST)
I want to extract the surface temperature according to the eDNA sample.

So, I decided to buffer the spatialpoints to 2 kms, which gives me spatial polygons.

To do that, I first got the coordinates from the samples.

```
PointCoordinates <- eDNA_species %>% select(ID, X_WGS84,Y_WGS84)
coordinates(PointCoordinates) = ~ X_WGS84+ Y_WGS84
```

Then, I did the following codes:

```
RST.Median2 <- raster::extract(RST,         # raster layer
                        PointCoordinates,   # SPDF 
                        buffer = 2*10^3,     
                        fun=median,
                        na.rm=TRUE,   
                        df=TRUE)
```

But... I am not sure of the results because there are overlapping polygons (see the picture)?

Here somme summaries:

1. RST

```
     RST
     class      : RasterLayer 
     dimensions : 11813, 15026, 177502138  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
     resolution : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
     extent     : 4.310566, 8.359992, 43.35413, 46.53767  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
     crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
     source     : RST.tif 
     names      : RST
```

2. Point coordinates

```
    summary(PointCoordinates) Object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame Coordinates:`
             `min       max
    X_WGS84  4.349552  5.964059
    Y_WGS84 43.382711 46.144236
    Is projected: NA 
    proj4string : [NA]
    Number of points: 193
    Data attributes:
           ID        
     Min.   :  1.00  
     1st Qu.: 50.00  
     Median :100.00  
     Mean   : 99.11  
     3rd Qu.:148.00  
     Max.   :196.00
```

3. RST. Median 2

```
    str(RST.Median2)
    'data.frame':   193 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ ID : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
     $ RST: num  18.2 18.2 16.9 16.9 18.2 ...
```

[image]

Comment: Don't see a picture or any summaries of your data. What does `summary(RST)` and `summary(PointCoordinates)` look like? What does `RST.Median` turn out to be? Is everything in the right coordinate system? Please edit your Q to clarify...

Comment: Sorry @Spacedman, I edited the question now.

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong? If you have points closer than your buffer distance then you'll get median values from sets of overlapping circles, but that's what you asked for. What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand well the tool but If one RST point is at the same time within eDNA polygon 1 and polygon 2, it would measure it twice know?

Comment: RST is a *grid* (and at 11,000 x 15,000 a very large one) and not what we'd usually think of as points. Your `extract` is taking each of the X,Y coordinates of `PointCoordinates`, and returning the median value of all the grid cells within a 2km radius of those points. If that's what you want, you've done it. If its not what you want, then you should probably explain more what it is you do want...

Comment: Thank you Spacedman. This is what I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the returned values will be the median of the grid cells inside the buffer distance, and each point is independent so if two points are closer than the buffer distance then their returned value will be calculated including some set of common grid points. Its not like one point is "using up" some of the grid such that there's fewer left for the adjacent point. I can't see any alternative mistaken interpretation that you might have had.

As ever with these things, creating a small example (with maybe a 20x20 grid and four points) would give you something easy to play with and test assumptions.